# What is more important on a cpu?

Tags: cpu, cpu-speed

What should be the criterion upon I should decide whether or not to buy a processor its speed? or the number of cores? meaning should I seek out a processor which is fast but has 2-3 cores or is it better to buy one with less speed but has a lot more cores?

Comment: Just so you know, this question is probably too opinion based and likely to be closed. Any way, it depends on what you want. Does the software you're using support multiple cores and threads etc? If the program you run is on a single thread, then having multiple threads won't help that program. Do you usually have lots of applications running at once? I think of it as CPU clock speed is how fast can it go. Cores - how many things it can do. And naturally you have a combination thereof. So, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: If you're not telling us what the computer is going to be used for, this question is way too broad.

Comment: Possible dupcliate of http://superuser.com/questions/324487/is-a-higher-core-count-or-higher-clock-speed-more-beneficial-to-a-computers-per